# How to implement object selection for an itemscontrol through a click action

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, datatrigger

I am in desperate need of assistance.

My app has been created in WPF and on the screen are two itemscontrols that use the same observable collection as the itemssource. One has the elements laid out in a grid and the other has the elements laid out on a ellipse based on x-y variables in the list.

However, I am stuck when trying to implement the following:
I want to click on one of the datatemplates generated on either the ellipse or the grid to select it and have BOTH corresponding elements glow or do something else to indicate a selection. (i.e. If I click on the template in the grid, both the grid and the ellipse will do something to indicate that template has been selected.)

Right now, I have been able to save the item clicked on using this type of binding in the datatemplate. The itemsource in question is contained inside ItemsSourceViewModel.

```
<StackPanel.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding SelectImage}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}" MouseAction="LeftClick"></MouseBinding>
</StackPanel.InputBindings>
```

Then the SelectImage Icommand that is bound to the mouseclick is implemented as such:

```
private ItemsSourceViewModel foo;

public SelectImage(ItemsSourceViewModel incoming)
{
    this.foo = incoming;
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;    

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return true;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var obj = parameter as ImageTemplate;
    foo.SelectedImage = obj;
}
```

So now my selected object is saved inside my instance of ItemsSourceViewModel, but how do I go about determining which template in both itemscontrols have been selected and how do I apply the triggers so they show that they have been selected?

Please help! :'(

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be an ItemsControl and not one of the Selector controls like ListBox?

Comment: It has to do with the way the uielement is styled and because the interface was originally meant to be read only, but the specification was expanded :(.

Also, using the selector control still wouldn't apply the selection across to the other itemscontrol

Comment: With a selector control you would have a two way binding to the selected item in your view model from both controls, and that would get you what you want (applying the selection across). If ListBox is out of the question you may end up having to implement selected item yourself, you will probably need it for other stuff as well. Shouldn't be too hard, a dependency property and / or a routed event.

Answer (score 0):

How About defining the input binding in your dataTemplate ItemTemplate. and maybe sending the name of your template as a parameter, then you could switch on the name of your template to do different handling?